# How to implement session idle timeout in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, session-timeout

I am using `Django==2.2.7`, `djangorestframework==3.10.3` and `django-oauth-toolkit==1.2.0`. Below is the config for limiting age of access token, I want to know how can I timeout idle session from server side. I tried using [django-session-timeout](https://github.com/labd/django-session-timeout) but it did not work. Please help.

```
LOGIN_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS      = 3600 * 24 * 365

# OAUTH 2 PROVIDER
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': LOGIN_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS,
    'OAUTH_DELETE_EXPIRED'  : True,
    'OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_backends.JSONOAuthLibCore'
}
```

Comment: The `LOGIN_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS` setting is already providing this functionality, no?

Comment: @IainShelvington idle session timeout and access token expiration are two different things.